# Is it possible to use Lusin's Theorem to derive Frechet's Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Frechet's Theorem states that every measurable function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is the limit of a sequence of continuous functions converging almost everywhere.

Frechet's Theorem is then used to prove Lusin's Theorem.

Is it possible to "use" Lusin's Theorem to derive Frechet's Theorem as a special case?

---

What I tried is use Lusin's Theorem to get a continuous function $f_k$ and a closed set $F_k\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_k|_{F_k}=f$ and $m(\mathbb{R}\setminus F_k)<\frac{1}{k}$. Then let $F=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty F_k$.
This looks promising as $m(\mathbb{R}\setminus F)=0$.

However I can't show that on $F$, $|f_k-f|\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Isn't there a problem in applying Luzin's theorem as the Lebesgue measure is not finite? (I went back to checking my notes, and the approximation argument is always done on finite measure spaces)

Comment: There is a extension of Luzin's theorem that works for infinite measure.

Comment: Your statement of Frechet's theorem is slightly misleading. It only says that for a measurable function, there is a sequence of continuous functions convergent to it almost everywhere. The class of functions which are limits of sequences of convergent functions is much smaller. You can iterate this by taking limits of sequences of those, and IIRC, you do get all measurable functions, but only after $\omega_1$ steps.